# Server 2003 R2 can access remote shares but unable to access shares that are on local server

Tags: network-share

We have a bizarre problem.  Suddenly some of our Server 2003 R2 boxes no longer are able to access shares if they are on the local machine, though they are able to access remote servers i.e. on server A I cannot access \A\share but I can access \B\share. To our knowledge .Net4, WIC and Trend were installed. Nothing else. We have uninstalled Trend. Anybody else experienced this?

Comment: What message, if any, do you get when trying to access a local share?

Comment: \\localhost\ gives me no network provider accepted the given network path

Comment: \\servername\c$ gives me is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact administrator of this server to find out if you have access permission. No network provider accepted the given network path.